# Find elements that occur in some but not all lists

Tags: python

Suppose I have several lists of integers like so:

```
[0,3,4]
[2,3,4,7]
[2,3,4,6]
```

What's the most efficient / most pythonic way to build a single list of all elements that occur in at least one list but do not occur in all lists? In this case it would be

```
[0,2,7,6]
```

Comment: Can you have repeated elements in the same list?

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: if you have n lists (and assuming no repeats), you want the numbers that occur between 1 and n-1 times across all lists right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is implied in your question .. if you substitute "set" for "lists". As StephenTG posted, simply get the difference between the union and the intersection of all lists.

The advantage of using sets over `Counter` is that you need make no assumptions about values appearing only once in each list.

The following works regardless of how many lists you have:

```
> list_of_sets = [set(l) for l in lists]
> set.union(*list_of_sets) - set.intersection(*list_of_sets)
{0, 2, 6, 7}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could take the intersection of all the lists as a set, and the union of all the lists as a set, and take all elements in the union that are not in the intersection. There are `union`, `intersection`, and `difference` methods to handle this that are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
>>> union_set = set(l1).union(l2,l3)
>>> intersection_set = set(l1).intersection(l2,l3)
>>> union_set - intersection_set
set([0, 2, 6, 7])
```

Or, as kdopen's answer shows, you can create a list of sets if you don't know the exact number of lists you'll be dealing with

Comment: What if you don't know how many of l1, l2, l3, ... there might be? Can you apply union to a list of lists, for instance?

Comment: That's why  I posted a separate answer

Comment: I selected kdopen's as it was written more generally, but thanks for this one

Answer (score 4):

If we assume each list contains an element at most once then you can use a counter to count the number of occurrences of each element. Then you can choose the elements that don't occur as many times as the number of input lists:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

lists = [
    [0, 3, 4],
    [2, 3, 4, 7],
    [2, 3, 4, 6]
]

print [x for x, c in Counter(chain(*lists)).items() if c != len(lists)]
```

Result:

```
[0, 2, 6, 7]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to post +1

Comment: This is cool but I went with generality for the selected answer.

Comment: This will only work properly if inner lists doesn't have repeated elements